# Importing simple products and associating them with grouped products

Tags: import, grouped-products

In my store I have grouped products and asociated simple products.

Is there a way to set simple products to a grouped product with importing file (csv, xslx,...)?

Comment: I don't think that default import profiles can do that. I am sure it could be added as customization

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with magento code - you can try next:

1) Extend/overwrite core class Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product

modify method `public function saveRow`

- add constants at the beggining of class

  const CSV_KEY_RELATED   = 'related';

  const CSV_KEY_GROUPED  = 'groupped';

  const CSV_KEY_CROSSSELL    = 'crosssells';

  const CSV_KEY_UPSELL   = 'upsells';
- add

  ```
      if (isset($importData[self::CSV_KEY_UPSELL]) && trim($importData[self::CSV_KEY_UPSELL]))
      {
          $this->setRelations($product, $importData[self::CSV_KEY_UPSELL], 'upsell');
      }

      if (isset($importData[self::CSV_KEY_CROSSSELL]) && trim($importData[self::CSV_KEY_CROSSSELL]))
      {
          $this->setRelations($product, $importData[self::CSV_KEY_CROSSSELL], 'crossell');
      }

      if (isset($importData[self::CSV_KEY_RELATED]) && trim($importData[self::CSV_KEY_RELATED]))
      {
          $this->setRelations($product, $importData[self::CSV_KEY_RELATED], 'related');
      }

      if (isset($importData[self::CSV_KEY_GROUPED]) && trim($importData[self::CSV_KEY_GROUPED]))
      {
          $this->setRelations($product, $importData[self::CSV_KEY_GROUPED], 'grouped');
      }
  ```

before line `$product->setIsMassupdate(true);`

- add new method:

public function setRelations($product, $data, $key)
    {

```
    $skus = explode(',', $data);
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $skus);    
    $ids = $collection->getAllIds();
    if (count($ids)) {
        $ready = array();
        foreach($ids as $id)
        {
            $ready[$id] = array('position' => '');
        }

        switch($key)
        {
            case 'upsell': $product->setUpSellLinkData($ready); break;
            case 'crossell': $product->setCrossSellLinkData($ready); break;
            case 'related': $product->setRelatedLinkData($ready); break;
            case 'grouped': $product->setGroupedLinkData($ready); break;
            default: return false;
        }
    }


    return true;
}
```

After all you can use columns 'related', 'crossells', 'upsells' - for any type of product. and column 'grouped' - for Grouped products. which should contain list of Simple SKUs, separated by comma